# "Unexpected MATLAB expression" when creating sparse graph

Tags: matlab

I have tried following code for creating sparse graph in MATLAB:

```
cm = sparse([1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5],[2 3 4 5 4 5 6 6],...
     [2 3 3 1 1 1 2 3],6,6)cm =
```

but it gives me the following error

```
???      [2 3 3 1 1 1 2 3],6,6)cm =
                               |
Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

I have taken this code from [the official site](http://mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/graphmaxflow.html), so I can't understand   why it produces an error.

Comment: It is time to start reading the BASIC tutorials, if you do not understand why such a simple expression fails to work. That spurious "cm =" you copied is trash, gotten from who knows where.

Comment: see it please http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/graphmaxflow.html

Comment: why downvoting first see site ,it can't be  such actions

Comment: It seems you've just missed the line breaks during C&P... Anyway it is a question for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't write the  `cm =` part at the end. That is, when you write

```
cm = sparse([1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5],[2 3 4 5 4 5 6 6],...
     [2 3 3 1 1 1 2 3],6,6)
```

on the command line, you will get

```
cm =

   (1,2)        2
   (1,3)        3
   (2,4)        3
   (3,4)        1
   (2,5)        1
   (3,5)        1
   (4,6)        2
   (5,6)        3
```

This is because, you didn't write a semicolon at the end of the statement. If you don't want to see the value of `cm`, just add a semicolon after the closing the parentheses. In addition `...` tells to write multi-line statement. You can write

```
cm = sparse([1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5],[2 3 4 5 4 5 6 6],[2 3 3 1 1 1 2 3],6,6)
```

alternatively.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, you have found a bug in the MATLAB documentation!

The `cm =` at the end belongs on the next line and is actually the output MATLAB gives you when you type

```
cm = sparse([1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5],[2 3 4 5 4 5 6 6],...
     [2 3 3 1 1 1 2 3],6,6)
```

MATLAB uses linebreaks to signify the end of a command unless you end the line with `...`, and after the closing bracket on your second line it doesn't understand what the `cm` is supposed to mean ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The MATLAB documentation has a typo, harmless to people with existing MATLAB background, but perhaps difficult to identify by beginners. To quote the [MATLAB document](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/graphmaxflow.html),

> ```
> cm = sparse([1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5],[2 3 4 5 4 5 6 6],...
>   [2 3 3 1 1 1 2 3],6,6)cm =
>
> (1,2)        2
> (1,3)        3
> (2,4)        3
> (3,4)        1
> (2,5)        1
> (3,5)        1
> (4,6)        2
> (5,6)        3
> ```

What it really meant to say was the following:

> ```
> cm = sparse([1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5],[2 3 4 5 4 5 6 6],...
>   [2 3 3 1 1 1 2 3],6,6)
>
> cm =
>
> (1,2)        2
> (1,3)        3
> (2,4)        3
> (3,4)        1
> (2,5)        1
> (3,5)        1
> (4,6)        2
> (5,6)        3
> ```

Notice that `cm =` is now on a new line and merely indicates the beginning of the output produced by the `sparse` function. What you have to do to create the sparse matrix from this example is to write

```
cm = sparse([1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5],[2 3 4 5 4 5 6 6],...
            [2 3 3 1 1 1 2 3],6,6)
```

This will give you the desired result.

In general, as some of the commenters pointed out, I would suggest going through a basic MATLAB tutorial before proceeding to more complex topics such as sparse matrices and graphs.